# Flies caught by 100 spiders in 100 minutes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, mental-arithmetic

I went through the following question:

If 5 spiders can catch five flies in five minutes. How many flies can hundred spiders catch in 100 minutes?

The answer is calculated by the following situation:

> No. of spider-minutes(same as man-hours term) = $5 *\ 5 $ for $5$ flies i.e. $25$ spider-minutes for $5$ flies.
>
> No. of spider minutes given $ = 100 *\ 100 $
>
> Therefore no. of flies $ = \frac {100 *\ 100}{25} *\ 5 = 2000$

I think the last step means to say

No. of flies $ = \frac {Given \ spider \ minutes}{original \ spider \ minutes} *\ 5$

But what is co-relating these 2 situations?

Comment: Assuming there is no cooperation between the spiders, each spider catches 1 fly in 5 minutes.  Hence 100 spiders catch 100 flies in 5 minutes.  Since there are 100 minutes, each lucky spider gets 20 flies, for 2000 in all.

Comment: the solution's just over my head...... thnx..

Comment: My favorite is: A five-person band plays a certain song in three minutes. How long does a ten-person band need?

Answer (score 1):

- $5$ spiders can catch $5$ flies in $5$ minutes:  $\frac{5\times 5}{5\times 5}\times 5$
- $100$ spiders can catch $100$ flies in $5$ minutes: $\frac{100\times 5}{5\times 5}\times 5$
- $100$ spiders can catch $20 \times 100 =2000$ flies in $20 \times 5 = 100$ minutes: $\frac{100\times 100}{5\times 5}\times 5$

*or*

It takes $25$ spider-minutes to catch $5$ flies.  You have $100 \times 100$ spider-minutes, so can catch $\frac{100\times 100}{25}\times 5$ flies.